# Database Error When I Delete a Channel in EE 2.9.0

Tags: playa

Using EE 2.9.0 and Playa 4.5.1

I tried to delete a channel in ExpressionEngine and when I did I got this error. Please advise?

---

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table 'mydb.exp_relationships' doesn't exist

DELETE FROM `exp_relationships` WHERE `parent_id` IN ('40')

Filename: models/channel_model.php

Line Number: 345
```